# Multiple header views in UICollectionView and designing them with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, interface-builder

When you drag a UICollectionView to a view in Storyboard you are able to design the header view for ***one section***. However if I have two or more sections in the collection view, how can I design those in the Interface Builder like I do with the first one? I understand that you must configure the data source methods correctly in order to return which of the header views to return.